# @Html.DisplayFor resulting in microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.internal.viewbuffer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

when using tag helper @Html.DisplayFor at some instances its returning microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.internal.viewbuffer in view instead of formatted value.

Its not happening for all usgaes, but at certain places its giving viewbuffer in output. For Example : when display for used for date format instead of displaying 30 jan 2019 its showing microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.internal.viewbuffer in view

Comment: What exactly is your question?  It's unclear.  If you want help, you're going to need to post code illustrating the problem.

Comment: Something like this : addonPrice.Total has 5.65 as value
Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => addonPrice.Total);
But on view it shows microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.internal.viewbuffer